# Querying DISTINCT records from existing content providers in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want Distinct records from content provider.

My current code:

```
String[] projection= {"_id","address"};
Cursor address =  getContentResolver().query(android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI,projection, null, null,"address ASC");
```

Comment: This is not supported. If you implement your own `ContentProvider`, you are welcome to expose a particular `Uri` pattern that will return `DISTINCT` results. However, the consumer of a `ContentProvider` cannot mandate that a `ContentProvider` implementation support `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score -1):

You can add DISTINCT keyword in columns names in projection. e.g.

```
String[] projection= {"DISTINCT _id"};
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That doesnt work with content providers. Throws error saying

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column DISTINCT _id

Comment: for me the error was "Non-token detected in", nor does ")GROUP BY(

Answer (score -1):

//use the DISTINCT before the name of the column

```
String[] projection= { "DISTINCT _id", "DISTINCT address"};

Cursor address =  getContentResolver().query(android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI,projection, null, null,"address ASC");
```

Comment: This gives the following error message java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column DISTINCT